# Mobile broadband won't connect

Tags: 13.04, mobile-broadband, broadband

I'm using an old laptop which I recently upgraded from ubuntu 11.10 to ubuntu 13.04. I updated everything and it all seems fine but after trying to connect mobile broadband (optus prepaid) through my huwaei e160e dongle, it doesn't recognize it or give an enable wireless broadband option in the network settings. This worked fine in my old install and I was wondering what I could do to fix it. It's frustrating as I can't connect to the net to try and download a fix so was wondering what to do. Any help appreciated.

Comment: copy this command to terminal 
dpkg -s modemmanager and give me output here

Answer (score 0):

Try going to: Network menu > Edit Connections > Add

Then choose mobile broadband from the list and follow the instructions provided.